# color shift when duplicating layers in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, layers

Duplicating layers within a single image shows a subtle colour shift. 
Duplicates are  subtly warmer (Our image high key greyscale, both as Grey and RGB, same problem)
Makes no difference if smart objects or simple dup layers.
No difference if Rgb or  Gs.
Histogram shows Numbers are identical across all layers (except for very small .01 difference in standard deviation)
This visual difference is visible in print
Best solution at this stage - duplicate 2x and discard original
Both CC and CS6 same issue
No blending or transparency
Any other solutions to try? Or similar experience?

Comment: It certainly _sounds_ like a transparency or blending mode problem. One thing you might not have already thought of: is there any inherent transparency in the image itself? You could try merging your image layer with a solid color background and then duplicating that to see if that does the trick.

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of your layer stack?

Comment: I voted to close this because it appears to be a software support issue. While common graphic design tools may be in use, this question doesn't appear to be about design.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a layer somewhere inside your file that changes the colors of whatever is underneath it, like hue saturation or levels or something like that. 
Here's how you check: On the layers window choose kind and then choose adjustment layer and you will be left only with adjustment layers, run them on and off untill you fint the one that's causing all the trouble